# CGPoint changes when orientations change

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

On the iPhone when the View is vertical as shown in the above diagram the X and Y values of a point is 10.0 , 15.0

[image]

But, when the phone is at Orientation right, what will be the value of this Point ?

How can I calculate this ?

Following code is what I tried. But, it doesn't convert the `rectSizeOfImage` when it is at orientation right setting.

I tried 2 approaches:

1.) tried changing orientations to right, top etc

```
if let img = context.createCGImage(ciimg, from: rectSizeOfImage) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: img, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
            }
```

2.)

```
let ciimg = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixBuff)
ciimg.imageTransform(forOrientation: 1)
```

Approach 2 also didn't work. I found the values for `forOrientation` by referring to the [Official Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/kcgimagepropertyorientation?language=objc).

Comment: I don't understand the question.. If the point is at (10.0, 15.0) relative to the top left corner, then when you rotate it, it will still be at the exact same spot.. Secondly, if you're trying to rotate the view itself, you can apply a `self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90.0 * M_PI / 180.0);`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking is "what is the position of the dot marked at (10,0, 15.0) in portrait after you rotate the screen 90 degrees counter clockwise?"

If that's what you're asking, there are two possibilities.

1) If you have rotation disabled for the view, it's still (10.0, 15.0), the portrait coordinates.

2) If the view rotates, the origin will be at the top left corner of the landscape screen, so, the rotated position will be (15.0, view.bounds.size.height -10.0).